# Pine script signal when bar closes higher or lower than pivot point open

Tags: pivot, signals, pine-script

I have coded a pivot point in pine script but now I want to add the S2-signal that indicates that:

1. a bar closes ABOVE the OPEN of the first pivot point bar (for an UPtrend) and
2. a bar closes BELOW the OPEN of the first pivot point bar (for an DOWNtrend)

This could take a few bars so I'm thinking a bar_index would be helpful but I can't figure it out (because I'm not a coder). Whenever there's a new pivot point, the check starts again.

If someone could help that would be great.

[[image: Plot]]

Answer (score 0):

if i understand what's you need:

```
trendup = close[1] > close and close > pivot point 
trenddw = close[1] < close and close < pivot point
```

But without a piece of source code is difficult understand